# Filling the icons of Tabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am making an tabbar application.

The icons, I have which is just a border -->
[image: This is what i have]

and i want this on select -->[image: Filled]

Setting the tint color just colors up the border.

How do i achieve this.

Note: I dont want to use two images, there is a better way to do it, as all apps-app store, music, Clock, Whatsapp, Facebook, Twitter use it.

Comment: You should have a "plain" black (and transparent background) .png.

Comment: It's they way they get rendered.  As Larme said you can have a plain black icon with a transparent background.  This is a great place to make the correct icons, and they work very well with iOS.  http://www.iconsberlin.com/free-ipad-iphone-tab-bar-icon-editor.php    You have to make them yourself, but it is very easy.

Comment: for that you need two different images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use setting your item as follows:

```
[controller.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ask_b"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ask"]];
```

the ask_b is the filling icon image. the system will not filling for you automatic, it's only support tint.